# Can't download updates anymore

Tags: package-management, software-center, update-manager

```
E:Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/restricted/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80],
```

and there are 2 more actually.

And now I have uncheck everything in other software tab.
I also reloaded the software download source to the main server.
what should I do with this kind of error ?

Comment: Give details of your system please. Which command are you trying to run?.

Comment: it happens after I close the softwae & updates section. sudo apt-get update didn't seems to work either. Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Please run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and provide the output. Are you running a supported version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @NeoTheThird - Xenial (*xenial-security*) for ARM (*armhf*) is supported. Comments should be used for clarification, not redundancy. Mr. President, is the internet access working and only apt isn't? If so you may want to try changing  to another server as the current one is down or in maintenance. Or just try again later.

Comment: @CelticWarrior - I was asking to rule out the possibility that he fiddled with the package sources.